# Run Jasmine tests from WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, jasmine, webstorm

WebStorm shows icons next to Jasmine's test cases and it seems as if there should be an option to run it, but the menu just says: *Nothing here*.

[image: WebStrom test suite]

As I did not find any documentation about this feature, I wonder if it should be possible to run tests like this and if yes, what the conditions are.

Comment: The "nothing here" is what it shows when you click on the green triangle? Or hover over it? Or?

Comment: It shows when I hover one of the two triangle icons.

Answer (score 2):

This likely means that no suitable test runners have been found. WebStorm doesn't manage test running directly. This job is done by a test runner. WebStorm supports several test runners - Mocha, Karma, Jest, JsTestDriver, nodeunit,... The logic used for determining what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in nearest `package.json` file.

Comment: it's a shame for payed IDE in 2018